# How do I make renaming and moving a file a loop given the common naming convention?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have these folder names (in the vector at the bottom) and my plan is to rename the files in each folder to match the folder names.

The file has the same name in each folder.

Here is how I've done it manually to this point:

```
setwd("C:/Users/filepathcontinued/hID_p=-1010097270")

file.rename("samefilepathineachfolder.csv","hID_p=-1010097270.csv" )

file.copy("C:/Users/filepathcontinued/hID_p=-1010097270/hID_p=-1010097270.csv", "C:/Users/chad/filepathcontinued",overwrite = TRUE, recursive = FALSE, copy.mode = TRUE)
```

My goal is to be able to run this as a **for loop** and pull the hIDs from the dataframe to determine the file path.

```
Folder_Names
1
hID_p=-1010097270
2
hID_p=-1011603482
3
hID_p=-1022839768
4
hID_p=-1123759962
5
hID_p=-1194277973
6
hID_p=-1250019159
7
hID_p=-1293571655
8
hID_p=-1364778807
9
hID_p=-1379668826
10
hID_p=-153130481
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I've understood the file structure but I think you could use this.
If there are a lot of files / folder it would be much faster to create a function and apply it to a vector of folders.

```
# Get the list of directories you are working on
directories <- dir(path = "C:/Users/filepathcontinued")
# Loop over these directories
for (i in 1:length(directories)){
  # Get into directory i
  setwd(file.path("C:/Users/chad/filepathcontinued",dir = directories[[i]])))
  # Rename the file
  new_file_name <- paste0(directories[i],".csv")
  file.rename("samefilepathineachfolder.csv",new_file_name)
  # Copy the file in the destination folder
  file.copy(new_file_name,
            "C:/Users/chad/filepathcontinued",
            overwrite = TRUE,
            recursive = FALSE,
            copy.mode = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: This is great. I am getting this error for some reason: Error in setwd(dir = directories[i]) : cannot change working directory! Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: So I ended up getting it to work by adding file.path to the working directory - thank you!........for (i in 1:length(directories)){
  setwd(file.path("C:/Users/chad/filepathcontinued",dir = directories[[i]]))
  new_file_name <- paste0(directories[i],".csv")
  file.rename("samefilepathineachfolder.csv",new_file_name)
  file.copy(new_file_name,
            "C:/Users/chad/filepathcontinued",
            overwrite = TRUE,
            recursive = FALSE,
            copy.mode = TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

```r
#vector of folders name
folder_name <- c('hID_p=-1010097270', 'hID_p=-1011603482', 'hID_p=-1022839768')

rename_copy <- function(x, src, dest){
  setwd(paste(src, x, sep="/"))
  f_in <- list.files(".")
  file.rename(f_in, paste0(x, ".csv"))
  f_out <- list.files(".")
  file.copy(f_out, dest, overwrite = TRUE, recursive = FALSE, copy.mode = TRUE)
}

lapply(folder_name, function(x) rename_copy(x, "C:/Users/filepathcontinued", "C:/Users/chad/filepathcontinued"))
```

File layout is assumed to be like below:

```
C:/Users/filepathcontinued/hID_p=-1010097270/file_inthis_path.csv
```

which will be copied to `C:/Users/chad/filepathcontinued` as

```
C:/Users/chad/filepathcontinued/hID_p=-1010097270.csv
```